# Why three families of multipole moments?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, multipole-expansion

There are three families of multipole moments: The electric multipole moments, the magnetic multipole moments and the toroidal multipole moments. Is there any reason why there are this three families and not two or four or even more? Are there for example symmetry reasons or something like this?

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct.  That classification of order $n$ multipole moments can be viewed as a symmetry classification of rank $n$ [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor), so how many of them there are is a matter of what symmetries exist in spacetime.

There are two types of "inversions" that can be performed on spacetime's two types of physical dimensions: a spatial inversion, also called a [parity inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)), and [time reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry).

The lowest-order multipole moment that's still interesting is the dipole moment, which is represented by a vector (a rank 1 tensor).  And the symmetry properties of a dipole moment can be classified by the four possible symmetry characteristics of a vector under the two types of spacetime inversions.

The following table, which was [lifted from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_moment#Symmetry_properties_of_dipole_moments), shows the symmetry properties under inversions of the various kinds of dipole moment.  In this table, a -1 in the P column means that the dipole moment changes sign under a parity inversion, and a +1 in the P column means that it doesn't change sign under a parity inversion.  Similarly, a -1 or +1 in the T column means that the dipole moment does or does not change sign under a time reversal.

[image: Dipole moment symmetry]

The symmetry properties of different kinds of higher-order multipole moments similarly relate to the symmetry properties of higher rank tensors.  For a (rather advanced) discussion of the symmetry of some of the higher-order multipole moments, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9806011.pdf).

Comment: So to understand this correctly: There are indeed two toroidal multipole families - the axial and the polar? But when I look at the formula, which is given at the wikipedia article for the toroidal moment, it is invariant under parity inversion (r -> -r), but changes sign under time inversion (j -> -j). So this should be the axial toroidal moment? And if so, how can the polar toroidal dipole moment be calculated?

Comment: I correct myself: It seems to me, that the toroid moment given by wikipedia is neither the axial nor the polar toroidal moment. And if so, how can the polar or axial toroidal dipole moments be calculated seperately?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the classical toroidal dipole moment is the polar toroidal dipole moment.  The classical one clearly changes sign under time reversal.  It also changes sign under a parity inversion, assuming that $d^3 x$ is really denoting the volume pseudo-3-form (which I do assume).  I presume that means that the quantum toroidal dipole moment involved in P-symmetry violation is the axial one, although I don't have access to either of the cited papers to verify that.  Presumably the cited papers describe how to compute the axial toroidal dipole moment that they use.

Comment: Whoops, scratch the last two sentences of my previous comment.  According to the WP article, axial toroidal dipole moments describe toroidal charge arrangements, and polar toroidal dipole moments correspond to the field of a solenoid bent into a torus.  The "classical" equation in the article is definitely the polar one; note that that equation involves current densities but not static charges.