# Introductory literature on the multipole expansions including toroidal moments

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, multipole-expansion

I wish to understand the general idea of the multipole expansion in the context of classical electrodynamics and, especially, the concept of the toroidal moments.  All the papers on the subject I've found cite this article (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037015739090042Z). However, the article appeared hard for me to grasp, from getting the general logic to following the equations. I wonder if someone can point me a more pedagogical exposition of the material. Main questions I would like to be addressed are

1) Why are there are three families of moments? I am aware of this question ([Why three families of multipole moments?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134277/why-three-families-of-multipole-moments)) referring to parity considerations, but my own impression was that it has more to do with the fact that the four-current $j^\mu$ has three independent components under the conservation condition $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$.

2) (Soft question) The fact that the toroidal family remained unrecognized until relatively recently appears surprising to me. If it is a part of some routine expansion (of potentials or something), why was it not noticed right away?

3) What is the simplest way to get the explicit formulas, at least for a first few orders? Most papers seem to be busy with writing the full expansions and not bothering to illustrate the basics.

I would not only be very grateful for the appropriate references, but also highly appreciate if someone shed light on the mentioned questions separately.

Answer (score 1):

The toroidal multipole moments are actually no independent family of multipole moments (see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.00755.pdf). Hence, the statements made by Dubovik in his 1990 paper and in his other papers are effictively wrong. The toroidal moments are just a higher order in the Taylor expansion of the electric parity multipole moments.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will give my feedback once I have a look.

Comment: As far as I can see, the paper stresses the fact that the radiation field patterns are the same for the toroidal and electric multipole families. Hence one can not separate one from another based on their coupling to external fields. However, if we speak about fields inside the sources and/or vector potentials, those are different for the two families. I would also question the statement that toroidal modes are just higher-order, but short of space here. Anyway, the point of view token in the article is interesting, but not the only one possible. I believe it leaves most of my questions open.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "fields inside the sources"? In Multipole Expansions, one only discusses fields which are outside the sources, usually on spherical shell with a large enough radius to enclose the whole sources. "Insides the sources", you would have to consider material properties, permittivities and effective macroscopic Maxwells Equations. But then, Multipole Expansions are not useful at all.

Comment: 'Inside sources' was probably a sloppy phrasing. I rather mean fields in the near-zone, not only at infinity. Multipole expansion, being a kind of a Taylor expansion, also works in the near zone if you include enough terms (you only keep the leading term when study radiation). And near-zone fields are different for toroidal and electric families.

Comment: Your last - right - statement is not more than an artefact of the Taylor expansion. If you consider only the first terms in a Taylor series, then you don't get an exact result. The fact that the near fiels of electric and "toroidal" dipole differ in the near-field stems from the different terms of the Taylor expansion that you consider.  In the far field, it is sufficient to take only the lowest terms of the Taylor series into account (hence the fields then are identical).  There was also a book published recently about this topic ("Toroidal Multipole Moments in Classical Electrodynamics").